# Twitter + Camel Using HTTPS / SSL

Tags: ssl, twitter

I use twitter4j+ camel plugin to read the tweets

```
<route id="twitter-timeline-incoming">
     <from
       uri="twitter://timeline/user?type=polling&amp;delay=180&amp;consumerKey=xxxx&amp;consumerSecret=xxxx&amp;accessToken=xxxx8&amp;accessTokenSecret=xxxxg&amp;user=user_account" />
            <process ref="setTwitterTimestampProcessor" />

            <filter>
                <method ref="twitterFeedFilter" />
                <to uri="direct:twitterProcessFeed" />
            </filter>
        </route>
```

Twitter has made it mandatory to use SSL from today, https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239

I would like to know how to enable SSL for these requests , which is not given in here 
http://camel.apache.org/twitter.html.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Jan 14 2014 Twitter updated it's API to require all endpoints be https. The default API endpoints in Twitter4J are http, rather than https. You can change them manually for now, until they update the defaults in Twitter4J:

```
    ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder=new ConfigurationBuilder();
    confBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
    confBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
    confBuilder.setHttpRetryCount(3);
    confBuilder.setHttpRetryIntervalSeconds(30);
    confBuilder.setRestBaseURL("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/");
    confBuilder.setStreamBaseURL("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/");
    confBuilder.setSiteStreamBaseURL("https://sitestream.twitter.com/1.1/");
    confBuilder.setUserStreamBaseURL("https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/");
    confBuilder.setOAuthRequestTokenURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
    confBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
    confBuilder.setOAuthAuthorizationURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
    confBuilder.setOAuthAuthenticationURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate");
    Configuration conf=confBuilder.build();
    Twitter twitter=new TwitterFactory(conf).getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameter to JVM to turn on SSL:
-Dtwitter4j.http.useSSL=true

At least this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Setting JVM is not an option for me,

Ticket has been raised in camel + twitter plugin

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7134 and seems a patch is available in fix versions 2.11.4, 2.12.3, 2.13.0